# I am running a backward feature selection model and cannot view the features selected

Tags: model, feature-selection

I have run a backward feature selection model as follows:

```
    backward_feature_selector=SequentialFeatureSelector(DecisionTreeClassifier(),
                                               k_features=6,
                                               forward=False,
                                               floating=True,
                                               verbose=2,
                                               scoring="accuracy",
                                              cv=5).fit(X_train,y_train)   
    feat_names = list(backward_feature_selector.k_feature_names_)


    print(feat_names)
```

I get this:
['0', '1', '2', '3', '9', '26']

26 is not even in my column index range.